# dredge function error - R package MuMln

Tags: r, statistics, static-analysis

I have to do statistical analyses on a data set. I would like to create all the possible models and to test them with the dredge function but it doesn't work. 
Indeed, when I type:

```
glm1<-glm(presabs~dca1+dca2+se1+se2, family=binomial(logit))
dredge(glm1)
```

I got this error:

```
Erreur in dredge(glm1) : 
'global.model''s 'na.action' argument is not set and options('na.action') is "na.omit"
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The issue with using `options(na.action = "na.fail")` is that it changes the global settings of R. If you have a large script, changing the global settings will potentially impact on other sections of your code where you implicitly rely on `R`'s default settings. There are two ways to avoid this:

1. After using `dredge` change the settings back via `options(na.action = "na.omit")`.

OR the better way...

2. Utilise the regression function's ability to set the `na.action` argument. In your case:

```r
glm1 <- glm(presabs ~ dca1+dca2+se1+se2,
            family=binomial(logit),
            na.action = "na.fail")
```

Answer (score 11):

See `?dredge`:

```
# Example from Burnham and Anderson (2002), page 100:
data(Cement)
options(na.action = "na.fail")   #  prevent fitting models to different datasets

fm1 <- lm(y ~ ., data = Cement)
dd <- dredge(fm1)
```

If you skip the second line, your described error pops up, as the models are fitted to different datasets (due to removal of NAs).

Comment: You might want to amend this to incorporate the answer below which is a better way of doing this.