# How to calculate all possible models for a given set of variables

Tags: r

I would like to find a command in R, in order to calculate all possible models for a given set of variables.
For example, for three variables x1, x2 and x3 there are 8 possible models:

```
m1: x1+x2+x3

m2: x1*x2+x3

m3: x1*x3+x2

m4: x2*x3+x1

m5: x1*x2+x1*x3

m6: x1*x2+x2*x3

m7: x1*x3+x2*x3

m8: x1*x2*x3
```

If I have 5 variables there are 6894 different models (including all possible interaction) but I would like to confirm with R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606549/how-to-run-lm-models-using-all-possible-combinations-of-several-variables-and-a)

```
options(na.action = "na.fail") # avoid getting an error

library(MuMIn)

fullmodel <- lm(y ~ x1 * x2 * x3)

dredge(fullmodel, fixed = ~ x1 + x2 + x3)
```

Comment: If I would lke to take constant the main effect of x1, x2 and x3?

Comment: @George I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Basically, I need to see the possible combinations, keeping constant the main effects of x1, x2, x3. I guess the result would be something like this: [1, 2, 3] [1,2,3 ,12], [1,2,3,13] [1,2,3,23] [1,2,3,12,13] [1,2,3, 12, 23]  [1,2,3,13 23] without interactions 123

Comment: @George if you want to omit the 3-way interaction, just do not consider it as a possible output model. It is way more complicated to try to tell the R function to omit it.