# Using dredge from MuMIn error: object not found

Tags: r

Code and output

```
 > dredge(regional ~ national, foreign, tbili2_recip, data = s2)
 Error in eval(.expr_beta_arg) : object 'foreign' not found
```

Sample data

```
 s2 <- structure(list(regional = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), national = c(0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), foreign = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), tbili2_recip = c(1, 
 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), tbili16_recip = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), tbili32_recip = c(0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), tbili33_recip = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), tbil_don1 = c(0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), tbil_don18 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), tip = c(0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), wit70 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), wit80 = c(0, 0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0), wit90 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), wit91 = c(0, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 0), weight_diff = c(-3, -9, -33, 18, -8, -26), weight45 = c(0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), weight70 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), weight_neg45 = c(0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), weight_neg70 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), work = c(0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am actually trying to do this for a few different variables than shown here, but all are having the same issue. 
Anything obvious I am overlooking? Variables are all numeric and it works in a typical lm().

I checked the other posts on stackoverflow on this topic with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
model <- lm(regional ~ national + foreign + tbili2_recip, data=s2)
options(na.action = "na.fail")
dredge(model)
```

You need first to fit a model (I used `lm` because it is the basic one)  and then you can use it as an argument to `dredge`.
Also, as you can see here [dredge function error - R package MuMln](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281739/dredge-function-error-r-package-mumln), you need the `options(na.action = "na.fail")` in order to make it work.
Finally, formulas use `+` and not `,` so we need `regional ~ national + foreign + tbili2_recip`